# How do I describe the difference between these two curves?

Tags: functions, soft-question, curves

How do I describe the difference between the following blue and red concave functions. I see that the blue curve is less steep closer to the origin, and more steep in the latter portion. Is the blue curve 'flatter' than the red one? Does it have a greater curvature

Is there a nice way to describe this? Is there some technical term for 'flatten'?

[image]

Comment: The blue curve is flatter than the red curve, which has more curvature than the blue one, which could be figured out by looking at the change in gradient.

Comment: So the blue curve is less concave than the red one?

Comment: The terms convex and concave apply to a closed curve. They are not comparative but absolute properties. For example an ellipse is a convex hull, but a cardioid is concave.